# When will implicit instantiation cause problems?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm reading C++ Primer, and it says:

"If a member function isn't used, it is not instantiated. The fact that members are instantiated only if we use them lets us instantiate a class with a type that may not meet the requirements for some of the template’s operations."

I don't know why this is a problem. If some operations are required, why doesn't compiler instantiate those operations? Can someone give an example?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12797051/implicit-instantiation-of-undefined-template-when-forward-declaring-template-c

Comment: Who said there's a problem?

Comment: @sashoalm That's not related.

Comment: That's a good thing. Otherwise you won't be able to use, say, the standard containers with move-only types, since their copy constructors won't compile.

Comment: @Potatoswatter The book says "may not meet the requirements for some of the template's operations", so I thought that was a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an ease-of-use feature, not a pitfall.

Lazy instantiation serves to simplify templates. You can implement the set of all possible member functions that any specialization might have, even if some of the functions don't work for some specializations.

It also reduces compile time, since the compiler never needs to instantiate what you don't use.

To prevent lazy instantiation, use *explicit instantiation*:

```
template class my_template< some_arg >;
```

This will immediately instantiate all the members of the class (except members which are templates, inherited, or not yet defined). For templates that are slow to compile, you can do the above in one source file (translation unit) and then use the linker to bypass instantiation in other source files, by putting a declaration in the header:

```
extern template class my_template< some_arg >;
```

Comment: Excellent answer. Many of the spurious trivia included that border on this and are frequently gotten wrong. Kudos

Comment: Of course it's also a maintenance pit-fall. Changes to templates that seem legitimate to the implementer (because they have declared pre-requisites to use the template) may break code that is 'weaving round' certain methods. Templates add very valuable flexibility but don't make the mistake of thinking it's a free lunch. The solution would be for the implementer to prevent lazy instantiation (all or nothing) and most probably have it disabled by default.

Comment: (PS. perhaps a mention of `POI` and/or _shallow instantiation_ is would be nice. And perhaps the use of static assertions in the class interface to do early concept checking)

Comment: @DanAllen Yes, it can be hard to provide good test coverage for template libraries. The upcoming Concepts feature will provide a facility for eager checking of prerequisites.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: It's odd isn't it? If I proposed you could instantiate a class with pure virtual functions so long as they never got called I'd get funny looks and rightly so. But for templates it's close to standard practice.

Comment: @DanAllen Templates have no equivalent of base classes, so the comparison doesn't really hold. If you never use the base class, the function shouldn't be virtual in the first place.

Comment: The comparison holds perfectly. Templates and Inheritance are entirely separate technical mechanisms but achieve very similar purposes. They both allow you to write code over here that will 'cooperate' with (possibly as yet unwritten) code over there to achieve complex non-trivial outcomes. The challenge in providing such features in a stable and reliable way without coupling is how does the code over here declare/advertise the prerequisites/invariants of the code over there to be admissable. In inheritance it's abstract/virtual functions. In templates its concepts - if it ever shows up.