# qt implicit instantiation of undefined template 'QList<VPNConnection>'

Tags: c++, qt, class, struct

First arriving at this issue, I looked at a few SO questions, of which half do not seem to apply and the other half, quite frankly, I just do not follow.

**Problem:**

This is a simple implementation of my issue,

> ERROR : implicit instantiation of undefined template 'QList`<VPNConnection>` '

Specifically, the `VPNList` object in struct `User_VPN_Info` is underlined with the above error.

*Something of note, it was mentioned in one post to have your "children" above the parent, else one would implement a type of prototype, thus the `VPNConnection` being ontop of the `User_VPN_Info`.*

**Basic Explaination:**

The struct `User_VPN_Info` should implement the struct `VPNConnection` in the form of a QList to hold multiple `VPNConnection`'s

**Bare Code:**

```
struct VPNConnection{
    QString ip,cipher,protocol;
    int port;
    bool lzo_compression;

    VPNConnection(){}

    VPNConnection(QString _ip, QString _cipher, QString _protocol, int _port, bool _comp){
        ip = _ip;
        cipher = _cipher;
        protocol = _protocol;
        port = _port;
        lzo_compression = _comp;
    }
};

struct User_VPN_Info{
    QString vpn_name, vpn_expire;
    int DaysLeft;
    QList<VPNConnection> VPNList;
                         --------              <<< --- underlined with error   
    User_VPN_Info(){}

    User_VPN_Info(QString _vpn_name, QString _vpn_expire, int _DaysLeft){
        vpn_name = _vpn_name;
        vpn_expire = _vpn_expire;
        DaysLeft = _DaysLeft;
    }

    QString getString(){
        return(vpn_name + " + " + vpn_expire + " + " + QString::number(DaysLeft) + " ; ");
    }
};
```

**I would like to understand what causes this error and why it occurs here?**

> ERROR : implicit instantiation of undefined template 'QList`<VPNConnection>` '

**UPDATE**

After some more research, I came accross [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12797051/implicit-instantiation-of-undefined-template-when-forward-declaring-template-c)

> user - dasblinkenlight
>
> apply as a pointer

Thus changing to:

```
QList<VPNConnection> *VPNList;
```

removed this issue.

**Anyone care to offer an explaination?**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That's because you didn't include QList header, so you are missing the definition of QList, which you need if you have a variable of that type at

```
QList<VPNConnection> VPNList;
```

However, it seems that you include some header (e.g. QString) that makes QList identifier available. Otherwise, you will get an error

> unknown type name QList

This explains why the solution of using a pointer works fine, since it merely needs QList to be forward declared.