# Pointer variable of forward declared template class?

Tags: c++11, templates

I have a class exactly as below.

But I get errors when declaring pointer var to my class. What's happening here?
There are some similar questions here but I couldn't understand why my case is not working as the pointer is of the class itself.

Edit:
going by aweebit's answer.

suppose now if I have an overloaded "foo" for printing any integer which is passed. is there some way i can use the same objA?
or will i have to create another objAA with template argument int? i will edit my question to reflect this.

do i really have to make a separate object for every data-type?
or is there some way i can achieve late binding at runtime?

code:

```
#include<iostream>

template <class T>
class A;

int main ()
{
    A* objA = NULL;
    objA = new A();
    
    objA->foo("some string");
    objA->foo(1);

    delete objA;
    objA = NULL;
    
    return 0;
}

template <class T>
class A
{
    void foo(T);
};

template <class T>
void A<T>::foo(T str)
{
    std::cout << str << "\n";
}

template <class T>
void A<T>::foo(T inte)
{
    std::cout << inte << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `A` is a *class template* (and since the template argument cannot be [deduced](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) *– only relevant since C++17),* you have to explicitly specify the template argument:

```cpp
A<const char*>* objA = NULL;
objA = new A<const char*>();
```

Or with `std::string`:

```cpp
A<std::string>* objA = NULL;
objA = new A<std::string>();
```

Another thing you will have to do is to move the class definition to the top of your file. This has to do with the fact that [*at the moment you create a variable of any type, the entire definition of that type must be available*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12797282/9861000) (this applies to normal classes, too).

And the last problem your code has is that you are trying to call `A::foo()` although it is a private method since class members are [private by default](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54596/9861000).

***Addressing your question in the comments:***

Once you instantiate the class template, the type parameter `T` is replaced with the corresponding argument (`const char*` or `std::string` in our case), and since C++ is a strongly typed language, you will not be able to pass an argument of a different type to `A::foo()` (unless it can be [implicitly converted](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion), but that is another story).

Since your class does not have any data, and so the `A::foo()` method does not use any member variables, you could take the risk and cast the pointer to a pointer to a different instantiation of the class template using [C-style cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast) or the C++ specific [`reinterpret_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast), like so:

```cpp
((A<int>*) objA)->foo(1);
reinterpret_cast<A<int>*>(objA)->foo(1);
```

But do not take it as a general advice. You really have to know what you are doing if you use something like that!

A better solution would be to use a [function template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template), since `A::foo()` only really depends on its argument's type. So you could get rid of the `A` class altogether and make `foo` a standalone function template, or, if you really want to keep the class (maybe you want to store some data in it?), you should consider making `foo` a [member function template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_template#Member_function_templates):

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class A
{
private:
    T data;
public:
    template <class U>
    void foo(U);
};

int main ()
{
    A<const char*>* objA = NULL;
    objA = new A<const char*>();

    objA->foo("some string");
    objA->foo(1);

    delete objA;
    objA = NULL;

    return 0;
}

template <class T>
template <class U>
void A<T>::foo(U value)
{
    std::cout << value << "\n";
}
```

Comment: okay, now if I have an overloaded "foo" for printing any integer which is passed. is there some way i can use the same objA? 
or will i have to create another objAA with template argument int? i will edit my question to reflect this.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a couple of details that were missing and an answer to your new question. Please take a look at it.